# SSRS Report PDF image rendering issue

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, reportserver

I am building a label report that requires the user to input a Bulk Order Number that will generate multiple labels. When viewed in preview mode and on the report server, images on the report for postage and company logo appear on every instance of a label (report page).

However when exported to PDF, these images only render on the first label (page)

I considered this may not be an issue, as the user could print from the report server when accessing the report. This isn't the case, as when trying to print, report server creates a PDF for you to print from. There are no other options regarding printing other than page size and orientation, a PDF seems to be the only method from which you can print from.

The images I use have the visibility controlled by parameters, so you can select 1st or 2nd class postage, and choose to have the logo visible.

Each image also has the `RepeatWith` property set to the Tablix that contains order and address details.

When exported to word, the labels all appear as desired with postage and/or logo images on each instance. This is a step I would like to avoid, as it would be much nicer to have the user print directly from the report server, even if this still requires a printer friendly PDF to be created.

I have attached am image to show PDF output.

Any ideas how I can get these images to render on each label (page)?

[image]

**EDIT**

Image of design page

[image]

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot of the design view of your report?

Comment: @iamdave What would you like to know from the design page? Pretty simple layout, tablix, overlapping images for postage, and a logo image.

Comment: There are many subtleties within SSRS that are not easily explained. Seeing is vastly preferable.

Comment: What region are the images in? Meaning header, body, etc?

Comment: @WEI_DBA all images in report body. No headers or footers on the page

Comment: A view of grouping, tablixes, and textboxes in the design view would be very helpful for this and the other question you posted previously about this report.  Are all these objects contained in a tablix or are they free floating textboxes?  Please post a screenshot of the design view.

Comment: @Steve-o169 see edit

Comment: I'm still a little unsure about the layout(which part is the tablix) but I think you might be able to put everything into a List object to get the desired result.  Just set it to add a page break between instances of the group(Order_no) and it should repeat everything as necessary.

Comment: @Steve-o169 The tablix contains the 3 text boxes, one with expression that provides Order_No, then Name and Address. This is grouped on Order_No, and this group has a page break after every instance. The tablix also has page break set to 'after', as I found this stopped the tablix and images being displayed right at the top of the page which was the issue in my other question. Not sure why changing the tablix to a list would change the rendering in a PDF?

Comment: The only thing currently repeating is the tablix.  The `RepeatWith` property doesn't really work as it should on .pdf exports.  I've had the same issue with items not repeating where they should and dropping everything into a list item solved the issue.  It basically removes the need for the `RepeatWith` property as it just repeats the one cell list for each instance of `Order_No`.  It's a pretty simple change -- give it a shot and see if it helps.  SSRS is weird like that sometimes.

Comment: @Steve-o169 You might well be on to something with that suggestion! When report is rendered using 1st Class postage image, everything looks great and images repeat on PDF. However if I try to change the postage to 2nd class using the parameter, the 2nd class image doesn't render properly, and the company logo also moves to the left. It appears to cut the size of the list box and therefore not display the images correctly.

Comment: You may need to set the `CanGrow` property of the list object to True.  This way the list item should stretch to accommodate the items inside it.

Comment: @Steve-o169 the list item creates a tablix and rectangle, neither of which have a `CanGrow` property

Answer (score 0):

Based on the design view image you posted, it looks like the only thing repeating is your tablix containing the address information.  The SSRS `RepeatWith` property doesn't seem to work well with .pdf exports so the workaround for this would be to drop everything into a single cell on a list object and grouping using the `Order_No` to repeat everything.  This should remove the need to mess with `RepeatWith` and give you the desired results.